# vim regex find and replace

Tags: regex, vim

I want to use a regex to replace some strings in my file. I search for:
`%s/^  [a-z]*/    /`
what I want to do is to replace every [a-z]* that have 2 whitespaces with the sane [a-z] prepended with 4 whitespaces. Is there any "inplace" replacement or how would I reach that with vim?

With best regards

Comment: Do you mean replace `[][]abcd` with `[][][][]abcd` in which [] stands for space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it more straightforward to use the `\ze` object to define the end of the match:

```
:%s/  \ze[a-z]*/    /g
```

so the `[a-z]*` is not included in the replace, but just used to match the relevant spaces.

Comment: This will also affect lines, prepended with 4 whitespaces.

Comment: I like that approach. It'll also be more efficient (I'd be surprised if that would ever lead to noticable speed differences, but hey, I'm a programmer).

Answer (score 5):

```
:%s/  \([a-z]*\)/    \1/g
```

should do the job; beware of running this multiple times, though because the result of the replace will match the input pattern :)

Comment: I am very sad this was down voted, that \1 is priceless! thanks for the awesome tip :)